# Calling a method returns <__main__ XYZ object at 0x01234567>

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, superclass

I'm going through a web-based python tutorial and the code below executes in the web environment the class has provided.

However, when I try to run the code locally in Anaconda I get the following result:

```
I'm Fido. I feel <bound method Pet.mood of <__main__.Pet object at 0x00000223BD4B74E0>>.
```

I see how using `class` and `superclass` can make my code better, and trying to figure out how to get the web based examples to work locally.

Here's the code:

```
class Pet:  
    def __init__(self, name = 'Kitty'):
        self.name = name
    def mood(self):
        #code simplified for SO example
        return 'happy'
    def __str__(self):
        state = "   I'm {}. I feel {}.".format(self.name, self.mood)
        return state
class Cat(Pet):
    def chasing_rats(self):
        return "I'll get you!"
p1 = Pet("Fido")
print(p1)
```

Comment: `self.mood` is a method not an attribute in the sense as `name` is. so since its a method which returns a str you need to call it as `self.mood()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.mood` is an instance method of the class `Pet`. So you need to call it as a method by including the parentheses as `self.mood()`

```py
class Pet:
    def __init__(self, name = 'Kitty'):
        self.name = name
    def mood(self):
        #code simplified for SO example
        return 'happy'
    def __str__(self):
        state = "   I'm {}. I feel {}.".format(self.name, self.mood())#updated this line
        return state
class Cat(Pet):
    def chasing_rats(self):
        return "I'll get you!"
p1 = Pet("Fido")
print(p1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
I'm Fido. I feel happy.
```

Comment: To be pedantic, `mood` IS an attribute (of the `Pet` class object), and `self.mood` is an _instance_ method (classmethods are methods that work on the class itself, not on an instance). I fully understand that such considerations might only confuse the OP (given the question itself), but a better wording would be, much more simply, "`self.mood` is a method, so you need to call it using the parens"

Comment: yeah i agree @brunodesthuilliers was just keeping it simple for the OP

Comment: yes I totally understand (and actually support) this - as I said, "such considerations might only confuse the OP" here -, and that's exactly why I suggest a wording that is not only more "technically correct" ("best kind of correct" as we all know) but also, first and foremost, way much simpler ;-)